# ExtJS multiple js

Tags: get, extjs-mvc

Hi can We call one JS file from one file to another file...Means multiple JS files. I have one panel in JS [like this](http://pastebin.com/E9BAJAxg) and if I called another JS file ,that should read this PANEL control values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one js file content in to another js file. Use use like this 
//file1.js

```
var tabs = Ext.createWidget('tabpanel', {
    cls: "auto-width-tab-strip",
    activeTab: 0,
    plain: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    defaults: {
        autoHeight: true,
        style: 'min-height:620px; padding:10px;'
    },
    items: [{
        title: 'tab1',
        loader: {
            url: 'tab1.jsp',
            scripts: true,
            loadMask: true
        }
}]
});



function myFirstFun(){

   something
   ......
   ......

}
//End of file1.js
```

You can reuse the above code Some where like this 
//file2.js

```
 var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Forum Search',
    height: 300,
    width: 600,
    renderTo: 'search-panel',
    id: 'search-results',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: tabs
});
Ext.get('someid').on('click', function(){
        myFirstFun();           

    });
//End of file2.js
```

Like this you can call the file1.js function in to file2.js, But you have include both js files in your html page.

I think this may help you.

Comment: No Here both should write in same js file na..[see 295 line here](http://pastebin.com/E9BAJAxg),here using html file after click. In that html ,Including .js file. Instead of that can use .js instead of .html

Comment: Include the js file which contains reusable code in to the final.html file then in another js file you can use the code.

Comment: In that way I m using multiple html files...I want to use single html for the entire application @siva565

Comment: I have one panel in JS and if I called another JS file ,that should read this PANEL control values? can u explain this clearly.

Comment: there are two js files, i want to a call function of 1st js into 2nd js. How

Comment: For your better understanding I've edited the my code. Check it. This may solve ur problem.